# Update logistic regression model intercept only

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a simple logistic regression model built on sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.

I am now working with a new dataset that has a different outcome rate. To improve calibration, I would now like to update the model against a subset of the new data by fixing the coefficients and modifying the intercept only. I know I can modify all the coefficients and intercept by training a new model, but want to try intercept modification only.

I do not see a direct sklearn function for freezing coefficients, so my idea was as follows...

For this new training set (df), take the linear sum of the values (df[features]) and coefficients from the original model (original_model.coef_) and add the intercept (original_model.intercept_). Then fit a new logistic regression to that. Then take the intercept from that regression and add it to the original model to update it. Pseudocode below.

```
#given some new training dataset "df" and feature columns "features" and outcome "y"

df['linsum'] = np.dot(original_model.coef_, df[features]) + original_model.intercept_

new_model = LogisticRegression().fit(df['linsum'],df['y'])

#given some new validation dataset df_val and feature columns "features" and outcome "y", my newly recalibrated predicted probabilities will be df['p']

df_val['linsum'] = np.dot(original_model.coef_, df[features]) + original_model.intercept_ + new_model.intercept_
df_val['p'] = 1 /  (1+ np.exp(- df_val['linsum']))
```